# Text to image conversion

Tags: php

I have made a 7project in which i have to convert text into image 
i have done it & save image also.  but i have a problem when i use new line in text then in image content are not come in new line it will dis7play in a line only 
But i want if user use new line tag then there should be new line in image also
you can see the output at   http://shaktiindia.in/png/

please tell me how can i insert new line in image also

Answer (score 0):

If at all possible, consider using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org). It can handle multi-line and other text specialties much better than PHP's GD which I'm assuming you are using at the moment.

[ImageMagick: Text handling examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#label_lines)